# Fb.api('/me where can I find list of available parameters

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've been looking for the documentation for what parameters we can use when calling this and what the response object would consist of. They give us this simple example

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
    'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
});
```

for the facebook [login setup](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web) but what if I wanted the users profile picture, etc....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

'/me' is just a shorthand for the userid of the logged in user. So it has the same fields as the User node, the docs for which are here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/

Comment: That's well and good that you know what /me means. But where is the facebook docs mentioning this? does anyone know ?!